# Have Serilog retain files by date (regardless of the number of files)

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I am using Serilog in my .Net Core application with the following settings:

```
"flushToDiskInterval": "00:00:10",
"outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff}-{Level}]: {Message} - ({SourceContext:l}){NewLine}{Exception}",
"rollingInterval": "Day",
"retainedFileCountLimit": 31,
"fileSizeLimitBytes": 5242880, //5MB
"rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true"
```

With these settings, Serilog will create a new file daily and also when the previous file size is 5MB. Thus, in a day I can have multiple files depending on the logging intensity.

I will like to keep the log files generated pruned by date (not by the number of files) regardless of the number of files.
Do I have to write a custom sink?

Comment: there's a lifecycle hooks facility. I've never looked at/neded it but would statr by looking at its tests